# How do I set up 000WebHost email in Outlook 2013/2016?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, smtp, pop3

I had the email set up to work flawlessly while using Google GSuite (formerly Google Apps, no longer using GSuite) & 000WebHost but am clueless on how to set up the email account to work in Outlook 2013 or 2016. My domain is purchased with NameCheap but 000WH (DNS provider) has autonomy on domain for mail & webhosting settings.

Any direction on settings to be changed on Outlook & 000WH would be greatly appreciated.

Fields & info I need clarity on:

- (Outlook) Account type - IMAP or POP3?
- (Outlook) Incoming Mail server address, what should this be?
- (Outlook) Logon Information - Is this my credentials for 000WH, my email address or my ISP?
- (000WH) Any changes to be made regarding the MX record or mail-forwarding?

[image]

I'm fairly new to the web-hosting realm, Azure was my previous go-to for hosting uni projects.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook's access mechanism is considered 'unsecure' by Google, so access is not allowed.
To enable this 'unsecure access', you need to allow it in the settings on Google.

Comment: I am no longer using GSuite so Google won't fall into the equation. @Aganju